# scala.MatchError : while creating a dataframe out of a with more 22 fields & further writing in to RDBMS

Tags: dataframe, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

First I parse the kafka message and then apply schema to the message. It prints the schema as expected which I use rdd.toDF().printSchema inside the foreach loop .. but when I try to save the data using the JDBC connection it gives me an error:

```
scala.MatchError: Enrich.Streaming.Samples$Person@7d7904f6 (of class Enrich.Streaming.Samples$Person

class Person (
             name        : String,
             id       : String,
             type: String,
             .....,
             .....,
             .....,
             .....,
             32 of them
            )
extends Product {

@throws(classOf[IndexOutOfBoundsException])
override def productElement(n: Int): Any = n match {
  case 0 => name
  case 1 => id
  case 2 => type
  ....
  ....
  case 31 => ...
  case _ => throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(n.toString())
}

override def productArity: Int = 32

override def canEqual(that: Any): Boolean = that.isInstanceOf[Person]

}

object Person extends Serializable {

def parse(str: String): Option[Person] = {
  val paramArray = str.split("\\|")
  Try(
    new Person(paramArray(0),
      paramArray(1),
      paramArray(2)
      .....
      .....
      .....
      ......

    )) match {
    case Success(trimarc) => Some(trimarc)
    case Failure(throwable) => {
      println (throwable.getMessage())
      None
    }
  }

}

}




val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

 val data = messages.map(_._2).map(Person.parse)

data.foreachRDD(rdd =>
    rdd.toDF().write.mode("append").jdbc(url,table,prop)
    )
```

would really appreciate it if someone could help me resolve the issue.

thanks!

Comment: are you creating  `class Person` yourself? Why not use a `case class` ? Further, any line # info that would point out where the problem arises?

Comment: hello maasg, i have more than 32 feature in class Person & in scala 2.10.4 case classes support only 22 feature for that reason  i had to creatw a class.   The error is at val data = messages.map(_._2).map(Person.parse)when im string to parse the kafka message

Comment: maybe that's a good argument to upgrade to Scala 2.11?